# Get the parameters.yml params in the AppKernel.php

Tags: symfony, parameters

Can anybody knows how can I get the parameters.yml (or _dev) in the AppKernel.php ?

I want to change the getLogDir() variables('mylogsdir') dynamicly ?

AppKernel.php :

```
$this->rootDir.'/'.$this->environment.'/'.$myLogDir;
```

parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    myLogDir: 'logdir'
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot
Fabrice

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

**In AppKernel.php :**

```
...
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
...
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
....
    public function getLogDir()
    {
        $array = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($this->getRootDir().'/config/parameters.yml'));
        // or 
        // $this->getRootDir().'/config/parameters_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml'
        $myLogDir = $array['parameters']['myLogDir'];
        return $this->rootDir.'/'.$this->environment.'/'.$myLogDir;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've the solution, here in the vhost under nginx :

```
 fastcgi_param SYMFONY__KERNEL__LOGS_DIR "/path/to/logs";
 fastcgi_param SYMFONY__KERNEL__CACHE_DIR "/path/to/cache";
```

And, in the AppKernel.php file :

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if (!empty($this->getEnvParameters()['kernel.cache_dir'])) {
        return $this->getEnvParameters()['kernel.cache_dir'].'/'.$this->environment;
    } else {
        return parent::getCacheDir();
    }
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    if (!empty($this->getEnvParameters()['kernel.logs_dir'])) {
        return $this->getEnvParameters()['kernel.logs_dir'].'/'.$this->environment;
    } else {
        return parent::getLogDir();
    }
}
```

thanks,

Fabrice