# Symfony $_GET parameters in AppKernel.php

Tags: symfony, parameters

I want to load different configurations based on symfony route get parameter. For example following

```
GET www.xyz.com/{version}/someSlug
```

I want to read the version parameter and based on that want to load different configuration files, like the way its done in controllers. But in the AppKernel.php. Is it possible like that?

Any help or hint would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I wrote an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38073972/3351765) to show how to access a yml parameter file in AppKernel.php, Hope that can help you

Comment: Hi @doydoy44 Thanks you for your reply. But as I mentioned above, I am trying to read parameter from route. Like in controller we do fetch it from Request Object.

Comment: Basically you cannot do this.  Symfony in effect "compiles" your AppKernel and all the related configuration.  You can't change configuration on a per request basis.  What you might do is to have a different app directory for each version and then have your web/app.php select the relevant app directory.  Somewhat painful at best.

Comment: @Cerad yes its actually possible. I am not trying to change any configurations. I am just trying to load one extra file. All I want is that version variable from the path. If I add like GET www.xyz.com/{version}/someSlug?version=v1, then v1 is accessible in $_GET like $_GET['version'].

Comment: I guess I was confused by the "load different configuration files" portion of your question.  Take a look at kernel request listeners for pulling out the version and then doing something before the controllers kick off: http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html  You will end up using $request->request->get('version') instead of $_GET.